# Null Value when converting to IQueryable with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I'm working with EF5 and I have a generic repository with a GetById method that can receive the include properties wanted like this one:

```
public virtual T GetByIdIncluding(long id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable  <T> query = DbContext.Set<T>().Find(id) as IQueryable<T>;

    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }

    return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

`DbContext.Set<T>().Find(id)` return the correct object, but when I cast it with as IQueryable then the value of variable query becomes null.

Why? How can I select only the entity with the Id sent by parameter and all the includings sent by parameter?

Example of usage:

```
var houses = Uow.Types.GetByIdIncluding(id, tt => tt.Houses);
```

Thanks in advance! Guillermo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DbContext.Set<T>().Find(id)` returns single entity.

`IQueryable<T>` is a `DbContext.Set<T>()`.

---

You can't include some properties after you selected single entity by id. Also you can't use `DbSet<T>.Find` after you included some properties, because result will be `IQueryable<T>`. What you can do - include properties and filter result by id later:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Including(
                          params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{            
    IQueryable<T> query = DbContext.Set<T>();

    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)    
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);    

    return query;
}
```

And later:

```
var types = Uow.Types.Including(tt => tt.Houses)
                     .SingleOrDefault(tt => tt.Id == id);
```

Also you can create method `GetByIdIncluding` in your concrete repository classes (not in generic repository):

```
public static Foo GetByIdIncluding(long id, 
                 params Expression<Func<Foo, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    return Including(includeProperties).SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);
}
```

**BTW** consider using lazy-loading (it's enabled by default).

Comment: I know, that's what I'm trying to resolve and don't know how.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! the only thing I don't like about that is that I need to retrieve everything from the database to filter later and get only one...

Comment: With `IQueryable` result filtering will occur in database - only one result will be returned

Comment: Oh, I see...since the run will be deferred. Thanks! great answer!

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.103%29.aspx `DbSet.Find` method returns an entity, not an `IQueryable` of your entity. Try setting the Include on the `Set` before calling the `Find` method.

Comment: Same as previous response...Cannot resolve symbol Find when I move the Find to the last line

Answer (score -1):

You need to move the `Find` to after the loop:

```
public virtual T GetByIdIncluding(long id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    var query = DbContext.Set<T>();

     foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
     {
         query = query.Include(includeProperty);
     }

    return query.Find(id);
}
```

Comment: If I use that code it complains in the line inside the foreach saying cannot convert IQueryable<T> to DbSet<T>.

If I replace the var with IQueryable, then the foreach is OK, but it says it cannot find symbol Find in the last line.

Comment: BTW, isn't there any way to filter first? Since I don't want to retrieve from the database all the entities with all the includes, to finally just use one of them.